# Is there a legendary drop cap?

Tags: borderlands-2

I am level 64 in Borderlands 2 and have been farming a boss (BNK3R) for the '[Bitch](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Bitch_%28Borderlands_2%29)'. I've been attempting to farm the Bitch for more than 14 hours, but still no luck.

So my question is: **Can I still get legendary drops at level 64 or am I wasting my time farming?**

Comment: Please use proper grammar and spelling when posting.  If people aren't able to understand what you're saying, they won't be able to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: **You can always receive legendary weapons and you are not wasting your time!**

However, there are several more effective ways in which you can farm for legendary weapons.

For example, you can farm Legendary Loot Midgets. I have been farming these little guys since forever and I have received several legendary weapons from it. They are surprisingly weak and you can check out this video for more info on how to farm them.

> When you receive the Mission Rocko's Modern Strife (By Brick), you can
>   go to Thousand Cuts and **No enemy will spawn** except for special
>   ones (including legendary loot Midgets). It's then really easy to open
>   all the boxes you will find in the area. If you are lucky you cant get
>   1 LLM every 6/7 Min without being bothered by other enemies.

> The other known solution is to farm them at wildlife exploitation
>   preserve. The trick is to **Never finish the "Doctor's order" quest**
>   so you can do it several time. You run all across the building to the
>   hall where they experiment on Skags. In this place you have a room
>   with 4 boxes, 3 of them always contain LLM if the mission is active.

Answer (score 0):

Legendaries can drop at any level (possibly excluding very early level, I know some guns like elemental ones don't seem to drop in single digits). Note that farming is very slow for some guns as the chances involved are single digit percents, possibly lower than 1% in some cases.

I know a friend was farming Bunker for quote some time and I dont' believe he ever got what he wanted. I have personally found legendaries not very worth grinding for (because they take a long time not because the guns aren't good). Instead I just beat up raid bosses or bunker/warrior because they give a good amount of Purple guns and sometimes, if you're lucky, a legendary, but usually not the specific one you want. Playing with friends seems to help the odds a fair bit though.

If you're farming Bunker remmeber to just save and quit without leaving the Bunker area to make him respawn, don't leave the area or you have to make the long trip again. Save and quit and you should spawn at the Bunker map.

Comment: Yes i know abut loot midgt they usually drop just relics.