# How can I improve my success rate when farming?

Tags: borderlands-2

I've bin farming old slappy for a very long time. I've killed him more than doc mercy and still no legendary. I am op8. How can I improve my chances at getting his drops?

Comment: You might check [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/159586/23580) as it is related. Also, please use proper English and meaningful question titles. Poorly written/titled questions are unattractive because they demonstrate a lack of care for the material, may be hard to understand, and could become less useful to other users.

Comment: Ya well i just read my post and it us, very

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want [striker](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Striker_(Borderlands_2)), since you mentioned you are farming [old slappy](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Old_Slappy). In that case the answer @skovacs1 linked won't help you. You can't really improve your success rate, the only thing you can improve is the execution speed. Get the best weapon you have and kill him as fast as you can, without taking the risk of dying (which increases kill time significantly). Also try to repeat the exact same routine all the time, because then you get better at executing it fast.

Comment: It wasn't an answer. It was a comment mentioning another answer as relevant. The OP never mentioned their reason for farming that particular boss so I was unaware of their intent and wouldn't assume, but the linked answer does clearly state that there is no cap on legendary drops. The comment was moreso to try and bring the quality of the questions this user asks up to par as this is not the first butchered English question from this user that has required editing.

Comment: @skovacs1 I never meant to critisize you, I forgot to type 'linked'. Since he stated he was farming old slappy, and he also mentioned killing doc mercy, I thought he might be going for the specific legendaries they drop. I based my answer on that, and told him that if that was indeed the case, your linked answer is not what he is looking for (hence the 'in that case').

Comment: Lol.. No problem. :)